# Let $2 \times 2$ matrix $A=(2,-2,-2,5)$ Find a $2 \times 2$ matrix M such that $A=M^tM$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

I was thinking to go this way:

Determine if $A$ is positive deﬁnite, if each of the eigenvalues of $A$ are positive. Then we diagonalize $A$. $A=PDP^T$. Thus we can let $C$ be the diagonal matrix whose diagonal entry is $√λ$. Thus $CC = D$
Now let $B = PCP^T$, and it remains to show that $B^TB = A$.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your idea is good, what kept you from pursuing it?

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that this way was right.

Comment: @AVP did you ever finish the proof? If so, you could answer your own question